# Combine data from two csv files and output into categories

Tags: python

I have two csv files: one with files/paths that have been altered and one with files/paths that have been deleted. I am trying to combine the two to make it easier to see what has been added, altered, or deleted.
For example in the csv with altered lines:

> ```
> Hello_World.py,/Users/name/DropBox/Other Test
> Essay.docx,/Users/name/DropBox/Other Test/XXX NEW
> Project.docx,/Users/name/DropBox/Other Test/XXX
> Picture.jpg,/Users/name/DropBox/Other Test/XXX
> ```

and in the deleted lines csv:

> ```
> Test.txt,/Users/name/DropBox/Other Test/XXX 
> Picture.jpg,/Users/name/DropBox/Other Test
> Project.docx,/Users/name/DropBox/Other Test/XXX/Path 3 test
> Essay.docx,/Users/name/DropBox/Project/Other Test/XXX/Path 3 test
> ```

As you can see if something was moved to a new folder (or altered), it repeats in the deleted and altered files.

I want the output to look like this

> ```
> Altered,Picture.jpg,new_path, old_path 
> Altered,Essay.docx,new_path,old_path
> Deleted,Test.txt,path,n/a 
> Deleted,Project.docx,path,n/a
> Added,Hello_World.py,path,n/a 
> Added,NEW Project.docx,path,n/a
> ```

I've tried a bunch of things but here is what has gotten me the closest. The conditional for determining if it is 'altered' works but for 'added' and 'deleted' it outputs all of the entries as both added and deleted (if that makes sense).

```
mc = open('Major Changes {}.csv'.format(directory),'w')
print('Major Changes',file=mc)
fieldnames = ['Alt/Del', 'File Name','Path', 'Original Path']
writer = csv.DictWriter(mc, fieldnames=fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()

with open('Altered {}.csv'.format(directory),'r') as a1, open('Deleted {}.csv'.format(directory),'r') as d1:
    reader1 = csv.reader(a1, delimiter=',')
    reader2 = csv.reader(d1, delimiter=',')
    next(reader1)
    next(reader1)
    next(reader2)
    next(reader2)
    file1 = set(a1.read().splitlines())
    file2 = set(d1.read().splitlines())
    
for line in file1:
    x1,y1 = line.split(',')
    for line in file2:
        x2,y2 = line.split(',')
        if x1 in x2:
            writer.writerow({'Alt/Del': 'Altered','File Name': x1,'Path':y1,'Original Path':y2})
        else:
            writer.writerow({'Alt/Del': 'Added','File Name': x1,'Path':y1,'Original Path':'N/A'})
            writer.writerow({'Alt/Del':'Deleted', 'File Name': x2, 'Path':y2, 'Original Path':'N/A'})
```

It outputs to a new csv. Please let me know if I need to clarify anything and thanks!! Also sorry if the formatting is off, I wasn't sure how to separate my data/outputs.

Comment: shouldn't be `x1 == x2` ? You can use `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code is executed - it is called "print debuging". And maybe then you will see where is your mistake.

Comment: why do you use `read()` if you could use `list(reader1)` to get rows already splitted on columns.

Comment: BTW: it would be more readable if you would read every file separatelly - not both in one `with ... as ` - and then you could even create function to do it .

Comment: you can't use `else` because you have to check `x1` with every `x2` in all rows in `file2` to confirm that `x1` is only in one file. It may need more complex method. OR you should get only filenames from both files and use `set(filenames1) - set(filenames2)` to get filenames which are only in first file, similar way `set(filenames2) - set(filenames1)`  to get filenames which are only in second file. And `set(...) & set(...)` to get filenames which are in both files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `else` for this because you have to compare `x1` with all `x2` in all rows in `file2` to confirm it file is only in first file.

You should get only filenames and use

- `set(f1) - set(f2)` to get filenames which are only in first file,
- `set(f2) - set(f1)` to get filenames which are only in second file,
- `set(f1) & set(f2)` to get filenames which are in both files

BTW: I use `io.String()` only to simualate file but you should use normal `open()` for this

```
import csv
import io

data1 = '''

Hello_World.py,/Users/name/DropBox/Other Test
Essay.docx,/Users/name/DropBox/Other Test/XXX NEW
Project.docx,/Users/name/DropBox/Other Test/XXX
Picture.jpg,/Users/name/DropBox/Other Test/XXX'''

data2 = '''

Test.txt,/Users/name/DropBox/Other Test/XXX 
Picture.jpg,/Users/name/DropBox/Other Test
Project.docx,/Users/name/DropBox/Other Test/XXX/Path 3 test
Essay.docx,/Users/name/DropBox/Project/Other Test/XXX/Path 3 test'''

#with open(Altered {}.csv'.format(directory)) as fh:
with io.StringIO(data1) as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh, delimiter=',')
    next(reader)
    next(reader)
    file1 = list(reader)

#with open(Deleted {}.csv'.format(directory)) as fh:
with io.StringIO(data2) as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh, delimiter=',')
    next(reader)
    next(reader)
    file2 = list(reader)

#print(file1)
set_filenames1 = set([row[0] for row in file1])
print('set1:', set_filenames1)

#print(file2)
set_filenames2 = set([row[0] for row in file2])
print('set2:', set_filenames2)

only_first  = set_filenames1 - set_filenames2
only_second = set_filenames2 - set_filenames1
both = set_filenames2 & set_filenames1

print(' first:', only_first)
print('second:', only_second)
print('  both:', both)
```

Result:

```
set1: {'Picture.jpg', 'Hello_World.py', 'Essay.docx', 'Project.docx'}
set2: {'Project.docx', 'Picture.jpg', 'Essay.docx', 'Test.txt'}
 first: {'Hello_World.py'}
second: {'Test.txt'}
  both: {'Picture.jpg', 'Essay.docx', 'Project.docx'}
```

And when you will have it then you can try to save in new files. But it could be easier to get now other information if you keep data in dictionary with `filename as key.

```
dict1 = {row[0]:row for row in file1}
dict2 = {row[0]:row for row in file2}

for name in both:
    print('Altered |', name, '|', dict1[name][1], '|', dict2[name][1])

for name in only_first:
    print('Added   |', name, '|', dict1[name][1], '| n/a')
    
for name in only_second:
    print('Deleted |', name, '|', dict2[name][1], '| n/a')
```

Result:

```
Altered | Essay.docx | /Users/name/DropBox/Other Test/XXX NEW | /Users/name/DropBox/Project/Other Test/XXX/Path 3 test
Altered | Project.docx | /Users/name/DropBox/Other Test/XXX | /Users/name/DropBox/Other Test/XXX/Path 3 test
Altered | Picture.jpg | /Users/name/DropBox/Other Test/XXX | /Users/name/DropBox/Other Test
Added   | Hello_World.py | /Users/name/DropBox/Other Test | n/a
Deleted | Test.txt | /Users/name/DropBox/Other Test/XXX  | n/a
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm new to python so this was really helpful thanks for explaining everything!!

Comment: The script works in isolation perfectly but throws an error when integrated into my full program that also creates the altered and deleted files. The error is " Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new_tests.py", line 80, in <module>
    next(reader1)
StopIteration" This occurs where I move down two rows in the code above to avoid the headers. Do you know a reason this might be occurring?

Comment: it can seems your file is empty or it has less lines then you expect and it can't move to next line.